# fitsSystemWindows not making the status bar transparent

Tags: android

I had an ConstraintLayout and I want to include the Collapsing Toolbar Layout in it. So, I followed this tutorial: https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

But, my status bar is not transparent, even after including fitsSystemWindows in almost every component in my XML.

Here's my style, used in the activity

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The XML layout is too big, so I put it on this gist: https://gist.github.com/guuilp/6e20ff9e00af8b85c858c5e832a17c34

Furthermore, the back button is not being shown too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the below to your theme, note that this requires minSdkVersion to be 19.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Then set `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` in the Activity where you want the transparent status bar.

Comment: Thanks man!! I also upgraded the minSdkVersion to 19 to this work. So, please, add this to your answer. One more thing to I make your answer the correct one: How I'm suposed to make the back button appear?

Comment: How does it look now? Are you saying the app bar never appears, or that the back button never appears on the app bar?

Comment: The back button never appears on the app bar. This is a child activity, where in the AndroidManifest I specify that.

Comment: To be honest, I suggest making a new thread to eliminate confusion for any future visitors. This is because the back button not showing is a completely different issue than your post title "fitsSystemWindows not making the status bar transparent". In your new post, I suggest you include the full "Java" code for the activity you are trying to display the back arrow in, otherwise it will be impossible to understand where the issue originates. I'd be happy to help once you create the post.